# How can I reference a particular page in an article?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm new to Latex and can't seem to find an answer to what is a pretty basic question: How can I reference a particular page in an article?

Is there a way of doing this within the `\cite{}` command or do I have to modify the reference in the .bib file?

Comment: \pageref{label} in your present article, \cite[page]{key} in citations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear, where should be your reference. If you want to point a page in your working article, `\pageref{your_label}`, where `your_label` is somewhere in the page, is a standard solution.

If you want to give an additional remark to the cited work (in particular a page number in an article), you can use `\cite` with an optional argument, e.g., `\cite[page]{key}`.