# Reference number and equation number in one square brackets.

Tags: citing

How to make the reference number and equation number from this reference appear in one square brackets.
For example: "Modified from [14, (8)] ...",  where 14 is the reference number and (8) is the equation number in the cited reference which will be added manually (no label).

Thanks

Comment: This is no different than referencing a page within an citation, using `\cite[page]{cite}`. See [How can I reference a particular page in an article?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328421/5764)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\cite[(8)]{key}`?

Answer (score 0):

I use natbib, in your preamble add:

`\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,square,comma]{natbib}%Format Citations`

In your document use:

`\cite[(8)]{yourrefname}`

to get:
[14,(8)]

Reference the natbib package instructions on page 7: http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf

It will also sort your references in the order they appear e.g., [1-5], [1,3,7].